# Why does MySQL decide to check tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've looked through a lot of MariaDB/MySQL documentation for an answer to this but have yet to find one. I am running MariaDB version 10.2.22 and have a bunch of MyISAM tables.

I understand that the table check utility is there to check if a table has errors. However, sometimes when I go to query a table, MariaDB automatically starts checking the table before running my query (presumably because of some problem that has occurred) which can take a long time for a large table.

My questions is, is there a way to tell in advance of querying a table if MariaDB is going to check it? What are circumstances under which MariaDB deems that a particular table needs to be checked?

I've tried things like querying information_schema.tables and `show table status` but those commands in themselves trigger a check of the table. I just want to know before I start querying a table if MariaDB is going to check that table and if so, why has it decided that the table needs checking at all?